# android xls file support

Tags: android, excel, xls

I am developing an application for Android with a small database. My client wants to be able to export the database in an .xls file for Excel.

Is the Java Excel API the right option for implementing this feature? I have read on some forums that it doesn't work well for Android.

Comment: Please consider posting some more info. Which library? What works and what doesn't etc..

Comment: I am talking about JExcel. I am interested if someone has developed for Android with it and if this API is the right choice for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jExcel in my Android project and it worked fine.